# Creating custom output based on a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

### Problem Description

I have a NumPy matrix `M` generated as follows: `M = np.arange(25).reshape(-1, 5) * 10`. I'm trying to create custom output lists based on this matrix for different values of `i`. The desired output for various values of `i` is as follows:

- For `i=5`, the output should be `[10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 80, 90, 130, 140, 190]`.
- For `i=4`, the output should be `[10, 20, 30, 0, 70, 80, 0, 130, 0, 0]`.
- For `i=3`, the output should be `[10, 20, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
- For `i=2`, the output should be `[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

I'm struggling to find an efficient way to achieve this. Can someone please help me with a Python code snippet that can generate these custom output lists based on the matrix `M` and the specified values of `i`? Thank you!

`M.ravel()[np.flatnonzero(np.triu(M, k=1))]` for `i=5`

Comment: I don't think the reshape step helps you.  But I don't see a pattern for the different `i`.  For a start print `M`, which should be 25 numbers 0 to 240 by 10s.

Comment: the reshape step is to create a 5x5 matrix. For i=5, the output is the upper triangular part of the matrix. For i=4, the output is the upper triangular part of the matrix excluding the last column. For i=3, the output is the upper triangular part of the matrix excluding the last two columns. And for i=2, the output is the upper triangular part of the matrix excluding the last three columns.

Comment: That reshape makes a (25,1) shape, not a (5,5).  Check it  There are `np.triu...` functions for making up triangles.

Comment: There was a typo. It should be reshape(-1,5).

Comment: I was using `M.ravel()[np.flatnonzero(np.triu(M, k=1))]` for `i=5`. But no clue for the other values of `i`.

Comment: simpler for i=5, `M[np.triu_indices(5,k=1)]`

Comment: Please clarify the logic behind expecting those outputs for those inputs by [edit]ing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array:

```
In [134]: M=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)*10
```

and the triu indices:

```
In [135]: idx = np.triu_indices(5,k=1);idx
Out[135]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]))
```

for i=5:

```
In [136]: M[idx]
Out[136]: array([ 10,  20,  30,  40,  70,  80,  90, 130, 140, 190])
```

zero out a column, and repeat:

```
In [139]: M[:,-1:]=0; M
Out[139]: 
array([[  0,  10,  20,  30,   0],
       [ 50,  60,  70,  80,   0],
       [100, 110, 120, 130,   0],
       [150, 160, 170, 180,   0],
       [200, 210, 220, 230,   0]])

In [140]: M[idx]
Out[140]: array([ 10,  20,  30,   0,  70,  80,   0, 130,   0,   0])
```

and so on:

```
In [141]: M[:,-2:]=0; M[idx]
Out[141]: array([10, 20,  0,  0, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])

In [142]: M[:,-3:]=0; M[idx]
Out[142]: array([10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```